# UnboundLocalError: Function can't run if order of statement is changed

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, local-variables

I have a global variable defined

```
x=100
```

This code works perfectly fine

```
def fn():
    x=1
    z=x+1
    print z             #2
```

But this doesn't works fine

```
def f2():
    z=x+1
    print z
    x=1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 1, in <module>
    fn()
  File "<pyshell#82>", line 2, in fn
    z=x+1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I am unsure why this happened. Is it the compiler trying to interpret x as local in case 2 but x hasn't been initialized?

Comment: If a function contains an assignment to a variable, and no `global` statement for it, that variable becomes a local variable.  The *location* of this assignment doesn't matter; Python parses the entire function before generating any code, as it has to know the scope of each variable to properly generate code dealing with them.

Comment: tq @jasonharper, but if I removed the line x=1 from f2() function, then there occurs no error. It takes the global variable 'x' as operand in z=x+1.

Comment: Right, if there is no assignment to a variable, it's automatically a global (since there's nothing else it could possibly be in that case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global` keyword to pull in and modify the global value of `x`.

Like so

```
x = 100

def fn():
    x = 1
    z = x + 1
    print z


def f2():
    global x
    z = x + 1
    print z # -> 101
    x = 1

f2()
```

This might be helpful as well - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but, I wanted to know why that might have happened as it could have allowed global variable x to be used in case 2

Comment: @Pax in `fn()` you are creating a new variable `x` that only exists in the scope of `fn()`, therefore, you can modifying/use it however you want. In `f2()`, you are wanting to read the global `x` and add 1. But, you then create another `x` inside that function after you print out the global value, essentially overriding the global `x` with a local `x`. Since the local `x` was defined after you first referenced it, Python is raising an error.

Comment: @Pax remember that computers are stupid. You have to be really specific. If Python were to just guess which x to use, the behavior would be unpredictable.